# Flutter - Background notifications not working in iOS

Tags: firebase, flutter, background, messaging, payload

I'm creating a public chat app in Flutter, and I **can't** receive **background notifications** on **iOS**, when I trigger the method `admin.messaging().send(payload)` from my Cloud Function.

Here's my payload in the Cloud Function :

```
var payload = {
  notification: {
    title: `My Title`,
    body: `My message`,
  },
  android: { priority: "high" },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        contentAvailable: true,
      },
    },
    headers: {
      "apns-push-type": "background",
      "apns-priority": "10",
      "apns-topic": "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging", // bundle identifier
    },
  },
  topic: `mytopic`,
};
```

I tried a bunch of different payloads :

- I tried notification + data
- I tried only data (no notification) (in that case, I have to locally display the notification, but it is not working because the function `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` is never called)
- I tried to change "apns-priority" to 5
- I tried using a token instead of a topic

I set up carefully all I need to configure, thanks to the official documentation :
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/

I also checked Github issues, like these ones :
[1041](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1041), [6112](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6112), [5988](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5988), [1644](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1644), [4300](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4300), [4097](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4097)

### What is working :

- Background and foreground notifications on **Android and iOS**, when sent from Firebase Console (in 'Cloud Messaging' section)
- Background and foreground notifications on **Android only**, when sent from Cloud Function
- **Foreground notifications on iOS**, when sent from Cloud Function

### What is NOT working :

- **Background notifications on iOS** when sent from Cloud Function
- When app is terminated, it does not work as well.

Comment: This issue is still open. Please check the following.
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/6290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue !

I simply removed the line `"apns-push-type": "background"` in my payload.
Now it is working.

It appears that the line `"apns-topic"` was useless as well.

Here is my final payload :

```
 var payload = {
    notification: {
      title: `# ${context.params.passion}`,
      body: `${newMsg["senderPseudo"]} ${
        type == "image" ? "a envoyé une image." : `: ${newMsg["message"]}`
      }`,
    },
    // Set Android priority to "high"
    android: {
      priority: "high",
    },
    // Add APNS (Apple) config
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          contentAvailable: true,
        },
      },
      headers: {
        //"apns-push-type": "background", // This line prevents background notifications to be displayed
        "apns-priority": "10",
      },
    },
    token: "dnqTQVso60GfnnuOjHv8_e:APA91bElr-K3xkQMdYHX8VMrMZNCYCjO4zJlGseRh25AS_GT7cg9zlOGdQl4KXvr88ypeWjZjrPzrLRHitsQ-JKQK057ZQb_36c_lfsNjHXbYMYI2iS3jV_HGWf7Ene-ZlPvOb0aRr8u"
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

As a comment to your own answer:

You should not leave it as empty as it may cause a bug

[Sending notification requests to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns#:%7E:text=If%20there%E2%80%99s%20a%20mismatch%2C%20or%20if%20the%20header%20is%20missing%20on%20required%20systems%2C%20APNs%20may%20return%20an%20error%2C%20delay%20the%20delivery%20of%20the%20notification%2C%20or%20drop%20it%20altogether.)

> If there’s a mismatch, or if the header is missing on required systems, APNs may return an error, delay the delivery of the notification, or drop it altogether.

the value you should set should be `'alert'`,

Other apn-push-type values: [apns-push-type header field values](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns#:%7E:text=The%20apns%2Dpush,tvOS%2C%20and%20iPadOS.)